# Angular error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GithubComponent -> String]

Tags: angular

I have searched and not found exactly the answer I'm looking for.  I'm NEW to Angular, so have patience.  I started an online course, but was assigned a task before I really got familiar with how Angular works.  I have an application that fetches data from Cloudwatch logs.  We have set up a Cloudwatch log to get GitHub data, hence the name of the component:  GithubComponent.  I was getting data yesterday!  But today, I'm getting this error, and a blank screen:

> Error:  Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GithubComponent -> String]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[GithubComponent -> String]:
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for String!

Why do I need a provider for "String"?  There's too much code to paste it all here, but here is the piece that matters.  In app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations:[
GithubComponent]
.....
```

I am getting no errors in VSCode for the Angular code.  Below is the pertinent part of github.component.ts:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-github',
templateUrl: './github.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./github.comopnent.scss'],
providers: [
DataService,
GithubFilterPipe
]
})
export class GithubComponent implements OnInit{
collection: any[];
data: any[];
constructor (
private _dataService: DataService,
private GithubFilter: GithubFilterPipe){}
ngOnItit(){
this._dataService.getGitHubData().subscribe(data =>
this.data = data.events;
this.collection = this.data;
this.loaded = true;
});}
```

Comment: Please give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the `GithubComponent` in the `imports` array not `declarations`.

Comment: doing that gives me a completely blank screen

Comment: Why? If it is a component, then declarations is where it needs to go.

Comment: You import modules and declare components. This answer does not make sense.

Comment: @annmcg I need a clarification.  Is GithubComponent something you wrote or is it part of a package you downloaded (example: npm install something)?    If it is something you wrote then it does belong in declarations but we will need to see the code itself to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: I added a comment yesterday with a bunch of code, but now it's gone.  I'll re-add the code shortly.  To answer the question, though, github.component is something we wrote

Comment: I am now working from a branch in the code, so I'm getting a handle on the CloudWatch log, but am getting an empty array back.  The github.component.ts first imports everything I need, then includes this: